# Task deadlocks on .Wait() while running on non-ThreadPool Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

My code seemingly deadlocks, but I can't figure out why. The code is a simple consumer/producer with some additional error/execution handling. The producer fills a ConcurrentQueue, while the consumer loops over the queue and processes its contents, 1 entry at a time.

Here's the twist: The queue contains async actions that need to be executed, the result of which needs to be awaited. This last part allows for some degree of error handling such as retrying. The async actions are SignalR calls that relay messages to a hub. A listeren of the hub is quite reliant on these messages, which is why the queue needs to be a little more robust than usual.

**EDIT: Here is the more complete code sample you have asked me for.** It does **not** deadlock. Please see the bottom of the question.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write( "Run how many tries?: " );
        int tries = int.Parse( Console.ReadLine() );

        ActionPump pump = new ActionPump();
        Random r = new Random();

        for ( int i = 0; i < tries; i++ )
        {
            // Fail 10% of the time?
            int failOrNot = (int)( r.NextDouble() + 0.9 );
            Console.WriteLine( "{0}: {1}", i, failOrNot );
            pump.EnqueueAction( new ActionWrapper( () => RandomlyTimeout( failOrNot ) ) );
        }

        while ( !pump.IsDone )
            Thread.Sleep( 10 );

        // NOTE: Check pump.rejects here to see if any ActionWrappers still have a Task and if the Task.Status is WaitingForActivation.
        Debugger.Break();
    }

    private static Task RandomlyTimeout(int failOrNot)
    {
        // When failing, wait "indefinitly" to fake a timeout.
        return Task.Delay(failOrNot == 0 ? 3000 : 10);
    }
}

public class ActionWrapper
{
    private static long NextId;
    private long? _id;

    private readonly Func<Task> _action;
    protected readonly TaskStatus[] ValidTaskStates = { TaskStatus.Created, TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation, TaskStatus.WaitingToRun, TaskStatus.Running, TaskStatus.WaitingForChildrenToComplete, };

    public long Id
    {
        get { return _id ?? (_id = ++NextId) ?? 0; }
    }

    protected Task Task { get; set; }

    public int FailureCount { get; protected internal set; }
    public bool HasSucceeded { get; set; }

    public ActionWrapper(Func<Task> action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    protected virtual bool VerifyTaskState()
    {
        // Don't execute the action again if the task is still busy.
        if (Task != null)
        {
            // If the task is somehow not still running, dispose of it.
            if (Task.IsFaulted || Task.IsCanceled || Task.Exception != null || !ValidTaskStates.Any(x => x == Task.Status))
            {
                // This must have been an unregistered failure, because the ExecuteInternal method always clears
                // the Task property when it detects a failure. Since it hasn't, we can also assume the failure
                // counter hasn't been incremented.
                FailureCount++;
                HasSucceeded = false;

                // If we have an error to log, log it.
                if (Task.Exception != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Discovered failure to execute ActionWrapper, the action with id {0} has failed {1} times.{2}", Id, FailureCount, Task.Exception);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Discovered failure to execute ActionWrapper, Task has status '{0}'. The action with id {1} has failed {2} times.", Task.Status, Id, FailureCount);
                }

                try
                {
                    // Dispose of the failed or canceled task.
                    Task.Dispose();
                    Debug.WriteLine("The existing task for action with id {0} that has failed {1} times has been disposed. Advising new task creation.", Id, FailureCount);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to dispose of corrupt task for action {0}.", Id), e);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Task = null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("The action with id {0} that has failed {1} times is still running, awaiting same task.", Id, FailureCount);

                // If the task is still running and in a valid state, don't execute the action again. We don't want
                // to execute the action twice, because we don't know what it does.
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("The action with id {0} that has failed {1} times has not succeeded yet, advising new task creation.", Id, FailureCount);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public Task Execute()
    {
        bool recycleExistingTask = HasSucceeded || !VerifyTaskState();

        if (recycleExistingTask)
        {
            if (Task != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("The action with id {0} that has failed {1} times has not succeeded yet, returning existing task.", Id, FailureCount);
                return Task;
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("The action with id {0} that has failed {1} times has already succeeded, returning empty task.", Id, FailureCount);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("The action with id {0} that has failed {1} times has not been executed yet, returning new task.", Id, FailureCount);
        return ExecuteInternal();
    }

    protected virtual async Task ExecuteInternal()
    {
        try
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);

            Task = _action();
            await Task.ConfigureAwait(false);

            HasSucceeded = true;

            Debug.WriteLine("The action with id {0} that has failed {1} times has succeeded.", Id, FailureCount);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            FailureCount++;
            HasSucceeded = false;

            Debug.WriteLine("Failed to execute ActionWrapper, the action with id {0} has failed {1} times.{2}", Id, FailureCount, e);
        }
        finally
        {
            Task = null;
        }
    }
}

public class ActionPump
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<ActionWrapper> _actionQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<ActionWrapper>();
    private readonly List<ActionWrapper> _rejects = new List<ActionWrapper>();

    private Thread _pumpThread;

    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }
    public int MaximumActionFailures { get; private set; }
    public int MaximumActionWaitTime { get; private set; }

    public bool IsDone
    {
        get { return !IsRunning && _actionQueue.Count == 0; }
    }

    public ActionPump(int maximumActionFailures = 5, int maximumActionWaitTime = 1000)
    {
        MaximumActionFailures = maximumActionFailures;
        MaximumActionWaitTime = maximumActionWaitTime;
    }

    public void EnqueueAction(ActionWrapper action)
    {
        _actionQueue.Enqueue(action);
        StartPump();
    }

    public void StartPump()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            if (IsRunning)
                return;
            IsRunning = true;
        }

        _pumpThread = new Thread(Pump);
        _pumpThread.Start();
    }

    private void Pump()
    {
        ActionWrapper action = null;
        bool canRepeatedlyFail = MaximumActionFailures > 0;

        try
        {
            IsRunning = true;

            while (IsRunning && _actionQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                /* Preparation code before running action. */

                if (_actionQueue.TryDequeue(out action))
                {
                    int originalFailureCount = action.FailureCount;

                    action.Execute().Wait(MaximumActionWaitTime);

                    // The action has timed out if it has not succeeded nor failed after waiting for the allotted time.
                    bool hasTimedOut = !action.HasSucceeded && originalFailureCount == action.FailureCount;
                    bool hasRepeatedlyFailed = canRepeatedlyFail && action.FailureCount >= MaximumActionFailures;

                    if (hasTimedOut)
                    {
                        // A timeout counts as a failure. If it times out too many times, we'll discard it.
                        action.FailureCount++;
                        Debug.WriteLine("An action with id {0} that has failed {1} times (excl.) has timed out.", action.Id, originalFailureCount);

                        if (canRepeatedlyFail && action.FailureCount < MaximumActionFailures)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("The action with id {0} that has failed {1} times (excl.) is requeued to be reexamined later", action.Id, originalFailureCount);
                            _actionQueue.Enqueue(action);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (canRepeatedlyFail && !action.HasSucceeded && !hasRepeatedlyFailed)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("The action with id {0} that has failed {1} times (excl.) is requeued to be reexamined later", action.Id, originalFailureCount);
                        _actionQueue.Enqueue(action);
                    }
                    else if (!action.HasSucceeded || hasRepeatedlyFailed)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("An action with id {0} has failed to execute too many times. Skipping execution and removing it from the queue.", action.Id);
                    }

                    if ( !action.HasSucceeded )
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine( "Storing reject action with id {0} forever. Use in debugger to see if it completes sometime.",
                                         action.Id );
                        _rejects.Add( action );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _rejects.Remove( action );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed to pump action with id {0}.{1}", action == null ? -1 : action.Id, e);
            /* Cleanup code */
        }
        finally
        {
            IsRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

In this code I'm trying to cover a couple of deadlock scenario's:
First, I though the ConfigureAwait would help because if the code "lands" on the same thread as the synchronously processing Wait call, we couldn't handle the catch block or the code that sets the HasSucceeded bool to true. The Wait call would block the thread, while the blocked thread wants to process the HasSucceeded = true statement.

Then, I figured that starting the pump using a Task.Run or TaskScheduler.StartNew would start the pump in a ThreadPool thread, or at least a thread that would be available for the Task system. Even though I use ConfigureAwait, the code after the await needs to execute and needs a thread. Because ConfigureAwait indicates it **doesn't have to** return to the same thread, it doesn't mean it won't **accidentally** pick the exact ThreadPool thread it was already running on to continue with. By starting a new manually managed thread, I hoped to counter this obscure case.

As a desperate attempt to throw the code off the SynchronizationContext that allows it to continue on a specific thread, I tried setting it to null. Though while debugging I found that runtime the context was already null.

What happens when running is that I get a log message saying the Execute is being executed. Then, after 10 seconds, I get a log message saying that the action has failed. This only occurs sporadically, i.e. once every 50 or 100 pump entries. I figured the rest of the ExecuteInternal method was deadlocking on the preceding Wait call.

But why is it deadlocking at all!? It doesn't have access to my SynchronizationContext, which is null anyway. What's going on?

*PS: I realize a Wait call is synchronous and by nature very susceptible to deadlocks, but I have no control over the Task returned by the action. The SignalR Task sometimes waits very long, if it even completes at all. In this case I want the option to timeout and retry the call by calling the action again.*

**EDIT:** At first I though the sample was deadlocking, because I had a few reject Tasks (when running with input 15 or more) that had Task.Status "WaitingForActivation". It turns out that this is simply saying "I'm ready to continue post-await-execution and/or return a value to the code that awaits me". After I added the Pump.IsDone to my code, I saw that these Tasks were eventually cleaned by the pump's retry code.

The reason I thought the original code was deadlocking, was because the SignalR messages were coming through to the UI, but the Tasks that sent them sometimes kept waiting (seemingly) forever. That is why I built in the retry code in the first place, but still the SignalR Tasks never completed even though the messages came through. I guess my problem is more of a SignalR one than a Task deadlocking one.

I have one final mini-question about Tasks though: What happens when a Task runs forever? Is there code observing this and shutting down these Tasks via a timeout, or will they just hog ThreadPool threads until the end of the application? If instead of the _rejects list, I just "leaked" the Tasks that still timeout after x retries, would they eventually be cleaned or would they cause a memory leak? How do I best handle this when I have no control over Task creation (preventing me from using built-in functionality to add a timeout or cancellation token during Task creation)?

Comment: Could you post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem? The code you've provided wouldn't actually compile, and isn't complete. It'll be a lot easier to help you if we can reproduce this.

Comment: I wonder if the `_action()` here is capturing sync-context or otherwise contributing to a deadlock... impossible to see from this example.  Heck, from this example, we  don't even know if  the `Task` is  ever  *started*, let alone whether it runs to completion inside the  timeout

Comment: Is this really a `ConcurrentQueue`? I thought there is only a `TryDequeue` on it(?)

Comment: It's pseudocode, I can't provide the entire sample because it invovles setting up SignalR and something to fill the queue etc.. It's a ConcurrentQueue, but I didn't want to type the whole TryDequeue part to keep it short. I'll see if I can find a way to make a short sample program.

Comment: why is `Pump` synchronous at all? Why aren't you returning `async Task` so you can `await` on execute? As a side note, have you heard of [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? It does exactly what you're after.

Comment: The most obvious issue in the code fragment you've offered is that your "Pump()" method exits as soon as the queue is empty. There's no evidence you ever start it again, so obviously processing would stop at that point. Simple producer/consumer is typically implemented using `BlockingCollection<T>`; it's not clear why you want to use `ConcurrentQueue<T>` directly. Also I doubt that `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null)` is helpful or correct.

Comment: In any case, the fact is: true deadlock (and it's not clear that's actually the issue here) is very easy to diagnose **given [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem**, and practically impossible to diagnose without one. If you want help debugging, you need to provide a good code example.

Comment: What makes you think it's a deadlock in the first place?
Can you put more logs inside the body of _action();

Comment: The question surely is interesting but the code and problem description *must* be trimmed down. I'll take another look when that is the case. Closing for now.

Comment: As I mentioned in the final edit, the code seems to be working fine and the problem lies elsewhere (with SignalR). So you won't need to read/run it anymore :). The final questions about Tasks are generic and don't depend on my code sample.

Comment: @Beijerinc Task is just another abstraction over Thread. Replace the word Task with Thread and you might get the answer. I will start: what if Thread runs forever... will anyone kill it at some point?

Comment: And more importantly, how could the runtime decide which tasks/threads are broken, and which just take a lot of time to complete? :)

Comment: @Luaan: True enough, but how can I? I can't, but I simply want to stop the task if it takes longer than I want it to take. What Max said is also true, but if they abstracted away the thread, I would think they would provide a means to stop it. However, the Task is created externally so I cannot provide a cancellation token. If I would have had a thread, I could abort it, but how can I "kill" a Task?

Comment: Well, for one, `Thread.Abort` is a really bad idea (you'll find plenty of reasons why on Google). Second, the `Task` is almost never associated with a simple `Thread` - it's either an asynchronous I/O operation (no threads at all), or a thread pool thread (you really don't want to abort those). If the API you're using doesn't allow you to abort its operation, either bug the authors to add an option (using `CancellationToken`), or, well, you're out of luck. The only relatively safe alternative is to launch the task in a separate process - at least that will not leak unmanaged resources. Much.

Comment: And just think about how the API would look *without* the `Task` - you wouldn't have *anything* to go on, you'd just pass a callback to the `Begin` method and hope for the best. That's even worse, because you can't even clean up after yourself (this way you can at least `await` with a timeout).

Comment: Thanks @Luaan, that answers my question. I was just thinking I was missing something obvious, but it's simply not there. I understand why now. It's better to know we have a memory leak and document it than to let the next poor developer find out the hard way. Thanks!